# Getting plot area dimensions before plotting

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 5.2 qt for interactive plotting.

I want to rotate some labels on my plot so that they are at a consistent angle relative to the coordinate grid.
For example, if I have a label at (0,0) which is rotated '45 degrees', I want it to point to (1,1) regardless of what shape the window is and how I zoom in.

I have implemented this successfully by working out the aspect ratio from GPVAL_X_MIN, GPVAL_X_MAX, GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE etc. and doing the appropriate math in my plot command.
The issue I have is that those GPVALs only update *after* the plot is updated. So if I zoom in, I see no change in the label angle, but if I then refresh the plot (or do another zoom to the same place) the angle then updates correctly.

Reading the docs I think it's expected that these variables update only after the plotting is complete - but I don't know how else to get the aspect ratio during plotting.

The below plot script demonstrates the rotation logic I have. It works correctly, but if for example the xrange is changed before a plot, then it requires a replot before the angles correctly update again.

```
# Define function to adjust angle based on window size and zoom
reorient(angle) = atan(tan(angle) * (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) * GPVAL_TERM_YSIZE / (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN) / GPVAL_TERM_XSIZE) - 180 * (angle < -90)

# Open a plot window 
plot x

# Plot text "45" at (0, 0) rotated by 45 degrees, with reference points at (-1, -1) and (1, 1)
set angles degrees
plot '<echo "-1, -1, 0\n0 0 45\n1 1 90"' using 1:2:3:(reorient($3)) with labels rotate variable
```

I'm keen to avoid needing a replot because forgetting to do so is a potential source of errors, and because the full plotting script I am running is quite slow, so having to re-render twice each time I zoom is painful.

Comment: RIght! You get these values only **after** plotting. So you need a `replot`. Please add some minimal (non-)working example with script and data. It makes it easier and more likely that you exactly get what you want.

Comment: I have on occasion used "set term dumb" to do a quick plot, fast but not very useful, then "set term <what you want>; replot" to get the real plot

Comment: How many labels do you want to place in reality? Is the number variable or fixed? Are label coordinates and angles provided within the script or read from an external file?

Comment: I'm plotting a couple of thousand labels. The data coordinates and angles are coming from a (potentially slow) command line call made from the plot command.

Comment: @grahamstratton could you please add an illustrative graph (despite wrong angles) to give an impression what you are aiming for? If possible with your several thousand labels. I'm wondering how you want to get several thousand labels readable into a graph.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot the labels from a file via plotting style `with labels` the angles apparently depend on the aspect ratio of the plot. And then you need the `GPVAL_...` variables to correct for it, as you tried. However, the values for these `GPVAL_...` variables of a plot are only available **after** plotting and would require a replot, which is not practical or desirable especially when zooming in interactive terminals, e.g. like `wxt` or `qt`.

There is a workaround:
Labels placed via `set label` are independent of the graph aspect ratio.

- put your coordinates and angles into an array (mis)using `stats`
- set labels in a loop

If your data is not in a datablock, but in a file the script needs to be adapted accordingly (with an extra `stats` to get the total number of lines).

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0 because of the use of arrays)

```
### add rotated labels with correct angle independent of plot aspect ratio
reset session
set term qt

$Data <<EOD
-1.0   -1      0
-0.5   -0.5   30
 0.0    0.0   45
 0.5    0.5   60
 1.0    1.0   90
EOD

N = |$Data|
array L[3*N]
stats $Data u (i=$0+1, L[3*i-2]=$1, L[3*i-1]=$2, L[3*i]=$3) nooutput

set for [i=1:N] label i at L[3*i-2],L[3*i-2] sprintf("%g",L[3*i]) rotate by L[3*i] font ",20"
set xrange[-2:2]

plot -x
### end of script
```

**Result:** (screen capture from qt terminal)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response!
I'm going to have to have a play with this, but I think that maybe there's some confusion.
When using plotting style "with labels" the angles do not depend on the aspect ratio of the plot - this is my issue. I want text at (0,0) which is rotated '45 degrees' to always point to (1,1).

Comment: @grahamstratton oops, right, my mistake. Labels plotted `with labels` are also independent of aspect ratio. I was mislead by the alignment the labels itself. Ok, then you actually don't want 45 degrees, but an angle which is 45 degrees in a square plot (+equal x,y dimensions) which changes with the aspect ratio (when resizing the window or zooming in). I will think about it.